# Parallel execution Python function which uses Cython memoryviews internally

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, buffer, cython

I am trying to parallelize a routine using [Joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html)'s `Parallel`, but it doesn't work because one of the underlying functions uses Cython's memoryviews, resulting in `buffer source array is read-only` (the same issue has been discussed [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2013-February/003384.html)).

I would like to understand why it happens (my knowledge of the low level machinery of Joblib is limited), and what I could do to work around it.

I know that using Numpy buffers avoids this problem (as mentioned [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2013-February/003385.html)) but that is not really a solution. The function in question slices an array inside a parallel `prange` loop: using Numpy buffers would mean I cannot slice the array without the GIL, thus I would not be able to parallelize the loop using `prange`.

Comment: Parallel is using multiprocessing and thus supports shared writable objects. Can you add the key parts of your code into your question to understand where you're stuck?

Comment: @PietroMarchesi I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40225962/6037118